# How to configure wso2 esb 6.6 analytics and dashboard

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have been using wso2 esb 6.6 and need help with in setting it up to view and monitor APIs. no matter i tried its not working, always shows empty dashboard.[image]

Comment: What did you do?

Comment: on the esb-home/conf/synapse.properties I changed mediation.flow.statistics.enable, mediation.flow.statistics.tracer.collect.payloads, mediation.flow.statistics.tracer.collect.properties and mediation.flow.statistics.collect.all to true

Comment: and this shows on the log org.wso2.extension.siddhi.store.rdbms.exception.RDBMSTableException: Could not execute insert operation for store 'ConfigEntryTable'

Comment: @NxN can you please add full exception message and which db you are using for analytics. and you can have look at the link for similar exception can you have a look at this 

https://mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/dev/2018-November/078729.html, looks like same issue   

,
 https://mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/dev/2018-November/078729.html